# Change format message on javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a table `Message` that contain:

```
 "message": [
    "New Message of the day",
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2"
  ]
```

I displayed it's result in the interface of my project, the displaying of the result is like this:

```
New Message of the day, Message 1, Message 2
```

How can I replace the `,` by a `##` by a small function ?

Thank you

Comment: We would really need to see the code that does the displaying to know exactly what needs changing, would it be possible to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join.

```js
var obj = {
  "message": [
    "New Message of the day",
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2"
  ]
};

console.log(obj.message.join("##"));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 let messages= [
    "New Message of the day",
    "Message 1",
    "Message 2"
  ]

console.log(messages.join('##'))
```

Comment: This is identical to the existing answer.

Comment: Same time maybe we posted

Comment: You can use array.map